# Java - .putAll( t ) into a hashmap puts also t into another hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

**Problem :** I've players. e.g. A defending player and a midfield player. First the defending player will be used. He will be putted into the hashmap of fieldPlayers and then at the bottom. He we be added to the hashmap of defendingPlayers. 
**Now** I've my second player, the midfielder. Whenever I want to add him to the hashmap of fieldPlyaers, and the line "*fieldPlayers.get("H").putAll(t);*" gets executed. The player is also added to the hashmap defendingPlayers, wright after that certain line.

```
            HashMap<String,Map<String, Player>> fieldPlayers = new HashMap<String,Map<String, Player>>();
            HashMap<String,Map<String, Player>> bench =  new HashMap<String,Map<String, Player>>();

            HashMap<String,Map<String, Player>> attackingPlayers =  new HashMap<String,Map<String, Player>>();
            HashMap<String,Map<String, Player>> midfieldPlayers =  new HashMap<String,Map<String, Player>>();
            HashMap<String,Map<String, Player>> defendingPlayers =  new HashMap<String,Map<String, Player>>();

            ArrayList<String> listAttackingPositions = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Sturm","Secondary_Striker"));
            ArrayList<String> listMidfieldPositions = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Mittelfeld","Left_Midfield"));
            ArrayList<String> listDefendingPositions = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Abwehr","Sweeper","Right-Back"));

            Player p  = null;
            for(int i=0; i < Math.max(sizeOutTeam, sizeHomeTeam); i++){

                    // If there exist homeplayers
                    if(homeTeam.get(i).entrySet().iterator().next().getKey()!= null){

                    // get the player, which is an object Player 
                            p  = listPlayers.get(homeTeam.get(i).entrySet().iterator().next().getKey());

                    // create a hashmap t, which is e.g.  <Messi, objectMessi>
                            HashMap<String, Player> t = new HashMap<String, Player>();
                            t.put(p.getName(), p);

                    // If the players starting minute is 0 then we put him in as a fieldplayer - otherwise he is a bench player
                          if((Integer)homeTeam.get(i).entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().get("start") == 0){
                                    sizeLineUp++;
                                    if(fieldPlayers.containsKey("H"))
                                            fieldPlayers.get("H").putAll(t); // <----Problem
                                    else
                                            fieldPlayers.put("H", t);
                                    homeRating += p.getRating();


                            }else{
                                    if(bench.containsKey("H"))
                                            bench.get("H").putAll(t);
                                    else
                                            bench.put("H", t);
                            }

                        // add the player into the hashmap which represents his position                        
                            String pos = (String)homeTeam.get(i).entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().get("position");

                            ////////////// Attacking players///////////
                            if(listAttackingPositions.contains(pos))
                                    if(attackingPlayers.containsKey("H"))
                                            attackingPlayers.get("H").putAll(t);
                                    else
                                            attackingPlayers.put("H", t);

                            ////////// Midfield players ///////////////
                            if(listMidfieldPositions.contains(pos))

                                    if(midfieldPlayers.containsKey("H"))
                                            midfieldPlayers.get("H").putAll(t);
                                    else
                                            midfieldPlayers.put("H", t);


                            /////////// Defending players ///////////////////
                            if(listDefendingPositions.contains(pos))
                                    if(defendingPlayers.containsKey("H"))
                                            defendingPlayers.get("H").putAll(t);
                                    else
                                            defendingPlayers.put("H", t);
                    }
```

Thus - Before the line : ***fieldPlayers.get("H").putAll(t);*** - defendingPlayers contains the defendingPlayer. As soon as ***fieldPlayers.get("H").putAll(t);*** is executed. ***midfieldPlayers*** is empty and ***fieldplayers*** contains now also the midfieldPlayer like it should be. But ***defendingplayers*** contains now the ***defendingplayer*** and the ***midfieldplayer***. -- which is strange because that code isn't executed at that moment and the midfieldplayer shouldn't be there.

I hope that someone can help me - it would be very practical if I can still use this setup. So that I can manipulate my players with looping over the midfieldPlayers or fieldPlayers etc...

Kind regards

Comment: As per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#putAll-java.util.Map- `HashMap.putAll` does exactly that -- put all passed arguments in the map. Can you provide a minimal compilable example that shows the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can end up sharing the same hash map in several places: when  one of the maps does not have an entry for "H", you make `t` the value for that key. Therefore, when you next time add items to that map, the added items appear in *all* the maps where `t` was inserted before. In other words, the error happens because the map was added to more than one position in some *previous* iteration.

The safest is to create a new `HashMap` when one does not exist for the "H" key, instead of using `t`.